Is there a way to wait a cloud run job execution through API Rest?
I'll like to wait a job execution which was triggered by a API call, like the following example:
curl --location 'https://run.googleapis.com/v2/projects/foo/locations/southamerica-east1/jobs/my-job:run' 

Gloud CLI, have the --wait argument to it:
gcloud run jobs execute JOB_NAME --region=REGION --wait

Is there a way to do the same with API call?

Yes. The —wait flag what it does is checking the state of the operation retuerned by the run API call until it's done or has an error https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.operations#Operation

Thanks @Puteri. So, when I run a job, it creates an operation, and I can wait success/error with operation/{id}:wait endpoint?

No, you have to make regular calls to the endpoint until you get a result. There's nothing like waiting for it. The cli does the same but keeps you “waiting” while it makes the calls to api. It's a simulated “waiting”.

Yes, will work too, but I found this endpoint which literally wait a response/error: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.operations/wait

Why do you use an async service if you want to wait for the response? I think the wait will have a max timeout to 30 minutes. In any case, it's not a good pattern. If your process is "short" use a regular Cloud Run service. If it's long, use async mode and query regularly the job status

@SidiBecker can work so you can test. In any case guillaume has a good point about the antipattern it represents waiting for the operation to be done

Thanks guillaume and Puteri. I thought about using a Job because my process can take more than one hour to complete, which is the maximum timeout I can have from Run Service. Also, I can't have two executions of my Job running simultaneously, for conflict data reasons. So, I thoght to wait the current execution complete to start the next job., using Cloud Tasks to manage the queue. Any other ideas?

Adding to the scenario mentioned above, Cloud Batch would be a good choice  instead Cloud Tasks to enqueue my jobs executions which cannot run simultaneously?

@SidiBecker Did you get a code snippet working? Thanks

Hi @JavierLopezTomas. In the end, I chose to use Cloud Run Jobs with a logical-queue on Redis. See the comments of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78488909/12030522
